# zabbix trigger based on one week old data

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

Iam very much new to Zabbix. i have tried my hands on triggers. what i was able to make out was it can set triggers on some constant threshold. what i need is that it should compare with the data which i exactly one week old for that exact time and if the change is above some particular % threshold then trigger an alert.

i had tried some steps like keeping the current data and one week old data in and external database and then querying that data with zabbix ODBC drivers but then i was stuck when i was not able to compare two items.

if i may be confusing stating my issue. let me know and i will be more clear with my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the last() function for this.

For example if we sample our data every 5 minutes and we want to compare the last value with the value 10 minutes ago we can use 
(item1.last(#1)/item2.last(#3)) > 1.2 - this will trigger an alert if the latest value is greater by 20% than the value 10 minutes ago.

From the documentation it is not very clear to me if you can use seconds or if they will be ignored (for example item.last(60) - to get the value 1 minute ago), but you can read more about the last function here:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions

Comment: hey thanks for replyig also want to know can i compare two items for alerts.
say i have two items which are populated from a db check and i want to compare them both based on the percentage. can i do it?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, you want to check if two different items have the same value?